# How to conjugate the verb when the subject is optionally plural?

Tags: plural-forms, conjugations

E.g. I have a sentence "*Your ticket(s) was/were sent to you by e-mail.*". I write *ticket(s)* because some recipients will receive one ticket, while others will receive several tickets. I don't want to write *tickets* because I want to underline the fact that the recipient might receive just one ticket. What is the best way to write the verb? *was*, *were*, *was/were*, *was (were)*...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would use the verb "to email" here. It is implied that e-mails are sent.

> Your ticket(s) were e-mailed to you.

I would use the plural conjugation because a reader will see the (s) and the plural will feel more apt.

This second option is acceptable:

> Your ticket(s) was(were) e-mailed to you.

I would advise against the second option, however, because it adds unnecessary length to the sentence. Your reader doesn't need to be reminded of the singular conjugation.

Edit: As user3169 has suggested, you might want to use the present perfect tense. This tells the reader that you have just now sent the email. Using the past tense implies a previously sent e-mail. I still recommend the plural usage, as did user3169.

> Your ticket(s) have been e-mailed to you.